# How to Get url from the iframe using PHP

Tags: php, iframe

How to get the youtube url from the below link?

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" 
 src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VvJ037b_kLs" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use regex and preg_match function

```
preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $iframe_string, $match);
$url = $match[1];
```

**UPDATE** if you have page generated with php or as inline html in php file, you can use buffers to get html out of php and then use regex on it:

first use `ob_start();` at the beginning of your page code or if you have some html before your php you can use it for whole page by adding:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

and the beginning of the php file, then at the end, you can get ob buffer in string and applying the regex:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<iframe src="foo.bar"></iframe>

<iframe src="baz"></iframe>
<?php

$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// find all iframes generated by php or that are in html    
preg_match_all('/<iframe[^>]+src="([^"]+)"/', $output, $match);

$urls = $match[1];
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: what if it's not a string and an actual frame in a webpage?

Comment: @pinkpanther you can use ob_get_contents function to get the content of the buffer. On the begining you need to run ob_start. ob_get_contents need to be executed after the iframe. And regex need to have iframe in it too.

Comment: what if there was no title attribute in the iframe?

Comment: @mc2 you don't need `title` attribute only `src`.

Comment: This answer is so cool!! saved my week!. 
` foreach($kolPro->find('div.video div div iframe') as $youTube)
       { 
        preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $youTube, $match);
        $kolsData['you_tube']= $match[1];
       } `

Answer (score 3):

```
public function makeiframevideo($url)
{

    // Youtube
    $ytRegExp = "/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/";
    preg_match($ytRegExp, $url, $ytMatch);
    if ($ytMatch && strlen($ytMatch[1]) === 11) {
        return "<iframe frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen class=\"pull-left\"  id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"405\"  src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/{$ytMatch[1]}?showinfo=0\" ></iframe>";
    }

    // Instagram
    $igRegExp = "/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?instagram.com\/p\/(.[a-zA-Z0-9\_]*)/";
    preg_match($igRegExp, $url, $igMatch);
    if ($igMatch && strlen($igMatch[0])) {
        return "<iframe frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen class=\"pull-left\"  id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"405\" src='{$igMatch[0]}/embed/' ></iframe>";
    }

    // Vine
    $vRegExp = "/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?vine.co\/v\/(.[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/";
    preg_match($vRegExp, $url, $vMatch);
    if ($vMatch && strlen($vMatch[0])) {
        return "<iframe frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen class=\"pull-left\"  id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"405\" src='{$vMatch[0]}/embed/simple' ></iframe>";
    }

    // Vimeo
    $vimRegExp = " /\/\/(player.)?vimeo.com\/([a-z]*\/)*([0-9]{6,11})[?]?.*/";
    preg_match($vimRegExp, $url, $vimMatch);
    if ($vimMatch && strlen($vimMatch[3])) {
        return "<iframe frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen class=\"pull-left\"  id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"405\" src='//player.vimeo.com/video/{$vimMatch[3]}' ></iframe>";
    }

    // Dailymotion
    $dmRegExp = "/.+dailymotion.com\/(video|hub)\/([^_]+)[^#]*(#video=([^_&]+))?/";
    preg_match($dmRegExp, $url, $dmMatch);
    if ($dmMatch && strlen($dmMatch[2])) {
        return "<iframe frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen class=\"pull-left\"  id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"405\" src='//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/{$dmMatch[2]}' ></iframe>";
    }

    // Youku
    $youkuRegExp = "/\/\/v\.youku\.com\/v_show\/id_(\w+)/";
    preg_match($youkuRegExp, $url, $youkuMatch);
    if ($youkuMatch && strlen($youkuMatch[1])) {
        return "<iframe frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen class=\"pull-left\"  id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"405\" src='//player.youku.com/embed/{$youkuMatch[1]}' ></iframe>";
    }



    $mp4RegExp = '/^.+.(mp4|m4v)$/';
    preg_match($mp4RegExp, $url, $mp4Match);

    $oggRegExp = '/^.+.(ogg|ogv)$/';
    preg_match($oggRegExp, $url, $oggMatch);

    $webmRegExp = '/^.+.(webm)$/';
    preg_match($webmRegExp, $url, $webmMatch);

    if ($mp4Match || $oggMatch || $webmMatch) {
        return $url;
    }

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function getHtmlElement($html,$startOfElement,$endOfElement)
{
    $startingPosition = strpos($html, $startOfElement);
    $endPosition = strpos($html, $endOfElement,$startingPosition);
    $foundElement = substr($html, $startingPosition,$endPosition);

    return $foundElement;
}

    $html = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/');
    $startOfElement = '<div id="guide"';
    $endOfElement = "<";

    $myElement = getHtmlElement($html,$startOfElement,$endOfElement);

    echo $myElement;
```

I was looking for a way to take html elements from url's but i didn't find one so i wrote this.It works just as shown in the example.After getting the element you can apply the same logic as the function i wrote to get a part of the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = '<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VvJ037b_kLs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> ';
$tmpDoc = new DOMDocument();

# Dirty hack to support utf-8 with loadHTML
# http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95251
@$tmpDoc->loadHTML( '<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $url );
foreach ( $tmpDoc->childNodes as $item ) {
    if ( $item->nodeType == XML_PI_NODE ) {
        $tmpDoc->removeChild( $item );// remove hack
    }
}
$tmpDoc->encoding = 'UTF-8'; // insert proper

$body = $tmpDoc->getElementsByTagName( 'body' );

if ( ! $body->length ) {
    return null;
}

$nodes = $body->item( 0 )->childNodes;

if ( empty( $nodes ) ) {
    return null;
}

echo $nodes->item( 0 )->getAttribute( 'src' );
```

Answer (score 0):

**My html webcode is:**

```
  <div url="doctor.videoLink"><div class="media-youtube-video">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YZvJZrfw5oo?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" id="widget2"></iframe>
</div> 
</div>
```

And i retrive **src** from **iframe** as :

```
foreach($kolPro->find('div.video div div iframe') as $youTube)
                            {
                                //$kolsData['you_tube']=$youTube->innertext();
                                preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $youTube, $match);
                                $youtubeLink= $match[1];
                            }
```